# SQL to HQL problem

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I want to write this query in HQL but I can't. whatevere I do it seems wrong and hibernate throws exceptions. Could you please help me?

```
select t.users from (select user_id as users,sum(score) as total from score group by user_id ) t where t.total=5225;
```

Comment: What did you try and what exception did you get?

Comment: Also, what's the entity mapped to the `score` table?

Comment: It's exception was can not execute query but using having syntax solved my problem!

Comment: I mapped Score class to score table. Note that it has an integer named score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not directly answer your question, but you could simplify your query. You can get rid of the subquery by using the `having` clause:

```
select user_id as users
from score
group by user_id
having sum(score) = 5225
```

Maybe this helps to satisfy Hibernate.